# groovy oracle - No suitable driver found

Tags: oracle, groovy, oracle11g, ojdbc

```
Groovy 2.4.12
Oracle Express 11.2.0.2
ojdbc6.jar
```

I've just installed Oracle Express created a new user with all privileges. I can connect to my `xe` instance from SQL Developer, so I know its running.

Groovy console, I've added `ojdbc6.jar` to the classpath and now trying this...

```
import groovy.sql.Sql;

def cl = Class.forName('oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver')
println cl // outputs 'class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver'

def db = [
 url: 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe',
 user: 'me',
 password: 'me', 
 driver: 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver']
def sql = Sql.newInstance(db.url, db.user, db.password, db.driver)
```

I get the SQLException "No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/xe".

For the connect string I've also tried `jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe` and I've also tried `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` for both loading and the driver parameter.

Is this combo not possible or have I missed something obvious?

**EDIT:**

Correct connect string is the no-slashes format.

Comment: you need to add it to the root classpath, not the classpath of your script.  Because DriverManager looks there...

Comment: When I was working with MySQL I loaded the driver in this manner and it worked.

Comment: *shrug* think you need to do: `GroovyObject.class.classLoader.addURL(new File('path/to/ojdbc6.jar').toURL())`

Comment: instead of adding it with the console (incase that wasn't clear)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out @tim_yates was almost there.

Needed this...

```
def f = new File('c:\\oraclexe\\app\\oracle\\product\\11.2.0\\server\\jdbc\\lib\\ojdbc6.jar')
this.getClass().classLoader.rootLoader.addURL(f.toURL())
```

No idea why MySQL worked without this!